# OSX launchd with su

Tags: perl, bash, sudo, launchd

I have the following script I want to run every hour.  I've set up the launchd to run every hour, on the following simple bash script:

```
sudo perl /Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables/awstats.pl -config=alpha -update
```

It doesn't run with sudo nor without sudo.  I need sudo for the script to work.  Not really sure how to get around this.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: People, please stop editing `launchd` to `launched`. `launchd` is an OS x program, not a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Cron jobs in `/etc/crontab` can run as root, and thus they don't need `sudo` to run, you just need `sudo` to edit the file initially.

Try adding your job to `/etc/crontab`, and if it doesn't work, provide the syntax you used to run it, and the output from attempting to run it from there, showing why it doesn't work.

Comment: Moving to launchd because crontab is deprecated in OSX.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo` runs a command as root; Launch Daemons run as root by default, so `sudo` is unnecessary and irrelevant. If the script is not running as a Launch Daemon, something else is wrong. Check /var/log/system.log for any errors launchd encountered trying to run the script, and maybe capture the script's output by adding something like this to the .plist file:

```
<key>StandardOutPath</key>
<string>/var/root/awstats.out</string>
<key>StandardErrorPath</key>
<string>/var/root/awstats.err</string>
```

Also, make sure you're running the script properly. A launchd .plist file doesn't parse commands like a shell command line, it expects you to hand it pre-parsed elements e.g. each command argument as a separate string:

```
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/bin/perl</string>
        <string>/Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables/awstats.pl</string>
        <string>-config=alpha</string>
        <string>-update</string>
    </array>
```

Comment: It seems I don't have permissions.  The script should be getting called, but the application is reporting permissions problems.  I also see that you're calling the perl script directly.  My bash script runs 4 perl scripts.  So I've separated the launchd entry and the actual script it runs.